# I need to find out a probability od drawing 3 cards with same color in R

Tags: r

would lke to ask a question.
We have a standard deck of 52 cards (4 colors, 13 values). We draw three cards at random (no return). I need to find out a probability od drawing 3 cards with same color in R. Please help and thank you. :) this is what ive got rn

```
cards <- c(rep("color1", 13), rep("color2", 13), rep("color3", 13), rep("color4", 13))
sample(x = cards, size = 3, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Depends on how many cards you draw, do you draw just 3 or n cards?

Comment: yes, only three cards. I need to find out what is the probability that the three cards will be the same color. :)

Comment: `1 * 25/51 * 24/50` which equals `0.2352941`. Your first card has to have some color (p = 1), the probability of the next having the same color as the first is the remaining number that are the same color (25) out of the total number of remaining cards (51), and the third would then be 24 / 50 remaining cards

Comment: @AllanCameron maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this the probability if you have 2 different colours, not 4? Or it's more a question how you define colour in the context of cards I guess

Comment: @starja could be a terminology issue, color vs suit. But hopefully the calculation is clear enough that OP can adapt if for their case, if needed.

Comment: The math solution is (13/52)*(12/51)*(11/51) but that is for one color since we have four just multiply by 4 and that is the result or do as did on the answer and create a simulation both should be close to 5.07%

Comment: @Bruno for four suits the answer is 1 * 12/51 * 11/50

Comment: @Bruno I'm not a native, so thanks for teaching me the difference between colours and suits in the context of cards :)

Comment: thank you so much guys, i am also not native, I meant suits :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution using 10000 simulations

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)

deck <- tibble(cards = c(rep("color1", 13), rep("color2", 13), rep("color3", 13), rep("color4", 13)))

check_all <- function(x) {
  if_else(condition = length(unique(x)) == 1,true = T,false = F)
}

deck %>% 
  rep_sample_n(size = 3,replace = F,reps = 10000) %>% 
  group_by(replicate) %>% 
  summarise(result = check_all(cards)) %>% 
  summarise(prop = mean(result))
```